# what is %% and /r mean in for loop in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I am mostly familiar with bash scripting not dos. So I have this command in a batch file I know is iterating over all the files in a directory. But I want to know what /r and %% mean. (i know %%i is referring to each file)

for /r %%i in (*) do (
echo %%i
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the above command actually is incorrect. the /r switch expects a root path to iterate, eg. `for /r . %i in (*) ...` or `for /r c:\xyz %i ...`
the %i is the replaceable variable in the for loop. (you can use a-z and a few other characters). the % is akin to the $ in bash.
note: use %i on the command line, but you need to double the % in a batch file.

Comment: No, the command without a path is perfectly fine. The path following /R is optional. It defaults to the current directory if no path is given.

Comment: I will choose this answer as correct since the answer suits what I am asking.

Comment: %%i is giving me full path plus filename. Can I extract filename only from %%i?

Comment: yes. `help for` lists the various possibilities. the filename alone is %%~ni

Answer (score 3):

`/r` - iterate through the folder and all subfolders, i.e. recursively.

`%%I` - placeholder for a path/filename

The above command simply lists all files in the current folder and all subfolders.